# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid register options "value" must be an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, hapi.js

I am trying to setup a nodeJS application that .
Using Hapi and PostgreSQL DB.
Referred all documentations but the error persists.
While server.register

```
server.register({
  register: require('hapi-node-postgres'),
  options : {
    connectionString: "Postgresdb://dbuser:dbpassword@localhost/dbName"
  }
}, err => {
console.log(err);
});
```

The error that is coming is:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ***AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid register options "value" must be an object
    at Object.exports.apply*** (/home/sc/code/Reporting(proto)/node_modules/hapi/lib/config.js:22:10)
    at internals.Server.register (/home/sc/code/Reporting(proto)/node_modules/hapi/lib/server.js:367:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sc/code/Reporting(proto)/index.js:16:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
(node:15989) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15989) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Please assist.
I am using 
"hapi": "^17.5.3"
"hapi-node-postgres": "^4.1.0"

Answer (score 0):

You are using v16 options for registering the plugin as that method is no longer support for the v17 try this [link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-v17-upgrade-guide-your-move-to-async-await)